# Check if record exits in python MySQL and if the record not found then let the user to add that record (via user input) based on choice YES/NO?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database

This is my coding but it is not working also i dont know how to implement mysql query in python script.

```
 def search_contact():
     list_contacts()
     search = input("please enter first_name : ")
     mycursor = mydb.cursor()
     if mycursor.execute("select * from contacts where first_name LIKE 'search'"):
         print("yes record found ")
     else :
         print("no record found ")

[I want to print like this in output][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
 def search_contact():
     list_contacts()
     search = input("please enter first_name : ")
     mycursor = mydb.cursor()
     mycursor.execute("select * from contacts where first_name LIKE %s", ('%' + search + '%',))
     if mycursor.fetchone():
         print("yes record found ")
     else :
         print("no record found ")
```

The above code checks if the cursor has fetched at least one record.  There are more efficient ways to do this in SQL (for example, using EXISTS), but this should work.  The key point is, you need find out whether the query has fetched any row from the database.

Comment: Yes it is working but how to print like this https://imgur.com/a/AjHYtNu also is there any way to let user add data if not found.

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it sort-out my problem.Note-Below is the small coding part of my project and is not formatted properly .

```
def search_contact():

    list_contacts()
    search = input("please enter first_name : ")
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(
      "select * from contacts where first_name LIKE %s", ('%' + search + '%',))
    if mycursor.fetchone():
      print("yes record found ")
    else:
     print("no record found ")
    choice2 = input("do you want to add " + search+"\t'y/n'? ")
    if choice2 == 'y':
        add_contact()
        list_command()
    elif choice2 == 'n':
        print("Thank you")
      else:
        print("Not a valid option")
def list_command():
print("Command Menu")
print("list - list all contacts")
print("add - add contacts ")
print("del - delete contacts ")
print("update - update contacts")
print("exit - Exits program")
print("search - search contacts ")
```